# In the following code, how to access the second argument?

Tags: c

```
char argvv[8][32];

int func(int n, ...)
{
    va_list vl;

    va_start(vl, 8);
    if (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        strcpy(argvv[i], va_arg(vl, char *));
    }
    va_end(vl);
    parseArgs(n, argvv);
    ...
}
```

In another file, I define:

```
void parseArgs(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("arg1:%s\n", argv[1]);  
        /* ????? I know this is not right; how to access the second argument */
}
```

Comment: How to write the code in proper way

Comment: first of format your code correctly, use proper indentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `va_start()` is wrong; it should read:

```
va_start(vl, n);
```

Thereafter, you can use `va_arg()` as you did.

Your `parseArgs()` function should be declared as:

```
void parseArgs(int argc, char argv[][32]);
```

and defined appropriately.  You're not passing a pointer to pointers; you're passing a 2D arrays of characters, which is quite different.  If you had a declaration of `parseArgs()` in scope for the call in `func()`, you'd be getting conversion errors from your compiler.

#### An SSCCE

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>

void parseArgs(int argc, char argv[][32]);

char argvv[8][32];

static int func(int n, ...)
{
    va_list vl;

    va_start(vl, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        strcpy(argvv[i], va_arg(vl, char *));
    va_end(vl);
    parseArgs(n, argvv);
    return n;
}

void parseArgs(int argc, char argv[][32])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("arg%d:%s\n", i, argv[i]);  
}

int main(void)
{
    func(3, "abc", "def", "ghi");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have marked what I have changed in your code with comments.

```
char argvv[8][32];

int func(int n, ...)
{
    va_list vl;
    int i;

    va_start(vl, n); // Changed this line
    if (i = 0; i < n; i++) // Changed this line
    {
        strcpy(argvv[i], va_arg(vl, char *));
    }
    va_end(vl);
    parseArgs(n, argvv);
    ...
}


void parseArgs(int argc, char argv[][32]) // Changed this.
{
    //argv[1] is the 2nd argument - argv[0] is the first
    printf("arg1:%s\n", argv[1]);   
}
```

C arrays start with 0 index.

Comment: Also note that the first argument (argv[0]) is, unless you haven't set one, the programm name.

Comment: @SBI Just because variable name used is argv & argc, doesn't mean it's command line arguments. In this case, it's isn't.

Comment: I assumend this had to be some sort of exercise. My bad.

Comment: @SBI - yeah, it may be an exercise.

Comment: Not a exercise, I an porting stressapptest(code.google.com/p/stressapptest/) to vxworks. vxworks not support command line argc/argv

Answer (score 1):

```
void parseArgs(int argc, char **argv)
{    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
}
```